# Adding sums from one table to a second table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables

```
Child_id (this is temporary table)
--------
1001
----------
1002
----------
1003
----------
1004
----------
1006
```

-

```
Child_id         Amount       (this table name is user_details)
-------------------
1001             100
--------------------
1002             250
--------------------
1003             100
--------------------
1004             150
--------------------
1008             400
```

Now I want to add the total amount from the 2nd table where two child_ids are the same into the 1st table.
For example, output for this table is 600 (adding amounts of 1001,1002,1003,1004).

Please could you help me do this.

Comment: The [tag:SQL-Server] tag is the microsoft product, I guess as you've added the [tag:mySQL] tag as well this is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have very big table then this variant is better

```
SELECT SUM(u.amount)
FROM user_details u
where exists (select * from tempTable t where t.child_id = u.child_id)
```

Comment: Thnks bro. very helfull your sol for me

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
SELECT SUM(u.amount)
FROM tempTable t
INNER JOIN user_details u ON t.child_id = u.child_id
```

This will result in the SUM of the amounts for the records that have child_id in both tables

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
This query is similar to [Filipe Silva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1385896/filipe-silva), except IFNULL check of the amount for exceptional condition.

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(SUM(ud.amount),0)
FROM 
    user_details ud
INNER JOIN 
    temporary_table tt
ON 
    ud.child_id = tt.child_id
```

Answer (score 0):

creating your table

```
create table temporary_table (total_sum decimal(18, 2)) ;
```

inserting data

```
INSERT INTO temporary_table
SELECT SUM(u.amount)
FROM tempTable t
 JOIN user_details u ON t.child_id = u.child_id;
```